# Iterate over an array of hashes and update each hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like below:

```
data[:array] = [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}, {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}]
```

I need to update each hash with new key-value pairs like below.

```
data[:array] = [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"},
                {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}]
```

I am trying to perform this as follows:

```
data[:array].each do |array|
  c_info = fetch_c(args: args) # Say fetch_c gives out c as output 
  d_info = fetch_d(args: args) # Say fetch_d gives out d as output 
  array.merge!(c: c_info, d: d_info)
end
```

I get the output:

```
data[:array] = [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"},
                {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}]
```

The hash is not updated in the second iteration. Please suggest.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: What is `args`? What is `fetch_c`? What is `fetch_d`?

Comment: `data[:array] = data[:array].map { |h| h.merge(c: fetch_c(args: args), d: fetch_d(args: args)) }`?

Comment: @sawa  `args` is some input for `fetch_c` and `fetch_d`..  And `fetch_c` and `fetch_d` are some methods that give me output as `c` and  `d`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin merge is not even updating the hash. I am getting the same hash as whatever I am passing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce the issue is if `fetch_c` or `fetch_d` is throwing error in between.

Steps to reproduce:

```
def fetch_c(i)
  10/i
end

data[:array] = [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"},{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}]

data[:array].each_with_index do |array, index|
    c_info = fetch_c(index-1)
    d_info = fetch_c(index-1)
    array.merge!(c: c_info, d: d_info)
end
# ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0

data
# => {:array=>[{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>-10, :d=>-10}, {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}]}
```

Please ensure that your methods are not throwing error.

Comment: No.. I am sure my methods are not throwing the error. because I can see the outputs when I add a breakpoint after those methods.